# multi-blog instance with docusaurus

Tags: reactjs, routes, documentation, docusaurus

Please I am trying to create another blog in my docusaurus documentation website. I have added the plugin, yet the path in my documentation is not working. Please help.

```
plugins: [
        [
          '@docusaurus/plugin-content-blog',
          {
            /**
             * Required for any multi-instance plugin
             */
            id: 'tutorial',
            /**
             * URL route for the blog section of your site.
             * *DO NOT* include a trailing slash.
             */
            routeBasePath: 'tutorial',
            /**
             * Path to data on filesystem relative to site dir.
             */
            path: './tutorial',
            postsPerPage: 2,
            feedOptions: {
              type: 'all',
              copyright: `Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()} Facebook, Inc.`,
            },
          },
        ]
      ],
```

[image]